# How to ignore subdirectories when enumerating directory entries in linux C

Tags: c, linux, console

I must ignore entries that are subdirectories. How can do that? I think I have to use `S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)` but I don't know how. Can you help me please?

Here is my code:

```
void recorrer_directorio(char *dir_name) {
    DIR *dir = NULL;
    struct dirent *ent;
    char fich[1024];
    char buff[4096];
    int fd;

    /* OPEN DIRECTORY */
    /*ESTO ES MI CODIGO*/
    dir = opendir(dir_name);

    /* TREATMENT OF ERROR */
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("aqui esta mi error");
        perror("Recorrer_Directorio : opendir()");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        /* Nos saltamos las que comienzan por un punto "." */
        if (ent->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        /* PATH OF FILE*/
        realpath(ent->d_name, fich);
        printf("MI RUTA COMPLETA DE FCHERO [%s]\n", fich);

        /* IGNORE DIRECTORY PATH */
        ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: Regular files may start with `.`, ignoring them might not be OK.  You could check for "." and ".." explicitly but you need a generic solution for other entries.

Comment: Also do not use `realpath` this way: it will only work for the current directory.  Use the concatenation as suggested by P.P. and use `realpath` on the resulting buffer, if at all necessary.

Comment: Finally do not forget the `closedir()` to avoid leaking precious handles.

Comment: if i need the complete path of file in "fich" , i do not to use realpath??

Comment: You do not need `realpath()`, just concatenate the directory and entry name with `snprintf(fich, sizeof fich, "%s/%s", dir_name, ent->d_name);`.  `realpath` simplifies embedded sequences such as `"/./"` and `"/../"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `d_type` to get the file type if it's supported on your system:

```
if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR) {
     /* ent->d_name is a directory. */
}
```

Otherwise, you can use [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) as follows:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

char buf[4096];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/%s", dir_name, ent->d_name);
struct stat sb;

if (stat(buf, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)) {
    /* d_name is a directory. */
}
```

Comment: thanks!  i was trying to use stat but couldn't for the library